# Word Wrap in matlab editor involving strings

Tags: matlab, text-processing, word-wrap

Thanks for the help in advance.  Usually using ... in matlab allows a person to wrap lines in the editor.  However when I enter something like this

```
error('Really long error message ... that I would like to wrap');
```

the "that I would like to wrap") portion loses its identity as a string.  Is it possible to wrap code like this in matlab, and if so how would I do it?

Edit:
The naive solution would be to break up the string into several strings, concatenate them, and save the result as a variable.  I would like a cleaner solution though.

Comment: Is there any algorithm on how to restrict strings for word wrap?

Comment: I don't know.  I could break the string up into several strings, concatenate them, then save the result, but that isn't really clean.

Comment: The main query still remains how do you concatenate? How do you select which ones must go to the first line and the next line and so on. Or do you want just one line of strings? If so, which ones must we skip? Giving it another read through your question, since you are asking for MATLAB editor, now it makes sense.

Comment: I would have to do it by hand.  Otherwise if I could determine the number of characters within the margins I could divide the string up by this number of characters.  Then it would be a matter of concatenating them and storing them as a single value.  Neither idea appeals to me lol.  It's the only thing that I have been able to think of though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if in the end the string is supposed to be one line, you can break out the string without having to divide the string by a given number. You don't have to do any calculation at all, each of your line does not need to be equal in length (or number of character) to the next line.

Here is an example which runs without error (mmmh ... other than the one intended obviously!) :

```
error([  
   'Really long error message ' ... 
   'that I would like to wrap ' ...
   'but each line in the editor doesn''t need to be the same lenght ' ...
   'because in the end it will be concatenated ' ...
   'in a single ' ...
   'line. The only thing that matters is to put a '' character at the beginning, and ' ...
   ' a ''... sequence of character at the end of each line' 
   ] );
```

Granted it is not very elegant, but the only additional requirement to the `...` is to add the `'` symbol at the beginning end end of each line. The lines do not need to be consistent, you can break them when you like.

Answer (score 2):

**Appproach 1:** I think you can try out a cell array approach if it suits your cleaner ways, though I guess it's conceptually similar to @Hoki's approach -

```
emsg = [{'Really long error message that we are trying really really '} ...
    {'hard to fit into one line, because if we do not, then we are '} ...
    {'doomed.'}]

error(horzcat(emsg{:}))
```

**Appproach 2:** Another approach could be thought of using `strcat` and this might be a tiny-bit cleaner and direct (at least when compared to the cell array approach) -

```
msg = strcat( ...
    'Really long error message that we are trying really really ', ...
    'hard to fit into one line, because if we do not, then we are ', ...
    'doomed.');

error(msg)
```